# need to return "\" not "\\" in applescript to build bash command

Tags: bash, terminal, escaping, applescript, character

Thanks for the help.
I'm trying to build a series of bash commands using Applescript. My problem is applescript using `\` as an escape character. so when it returns my strings its returning `\\` not `\` as needed. Has anyone found a way to return a string with a single `\`?

Also, previous help I've received on this people will say "if you display dialog it will say `\` not `\\`" which is correct however I'm not attempting to display text I need to pass these strings on to bash.

```
--get all the finder info

tell application "Finder"
    set selCnt to selection as list
    if (count of items in selCnt) is equal to 1 then
        set theDir to the selection as alias
        set theDir to POSIX path of theDir
    else if ((count of items in selCnt) is greater than 1) then
        display dialog "Please select only one directory. ie: 'Documents'"
    else if (count of items in selCnt) is equal to 0 then
        set theDir to target of window 1 as alias
        set theDir to POSIX path of theDir
    else
        display dialog "What do you think you're doing?"
    end if

end tell

--rename strings with spaces

set t to theDir
set t to tid(t, " ") -- converts to a list of text items
set t to tid(t, "\\ ") -- converts back to tex a list odf text items
on tid(input, delim)
    set {oldTID, my text item delimiters} to {my text item delimiters, delim}
    if class of input is list then
        set outputA to input as text
    else
        set outputA to text items of input
    end if
    set my text item delimiters to oldTID
    return outputA
end tid
set theDir to result

--strings setup

set cdStr to "cd " & theDir
set stringA to ".doc"
set stringB to "\\"
set delDoc to "find . -name " & quoted form of stringA & " -exec rm {} " & stringB & ":"

set stringA to ".exl"
set stringB to "\\"
set delExl to "find . -name " & quoted form of stringA & " -exec rm {} " & stringB & ":"

--execute shell scripts

set theCmd to cdStr & return & delDoc & return & delExl

return theCmd


(*
do shell script cdStr
do shell script delExl
do shell script delDoc
*)
```

Comment: Could you please wrap your code so it is easier to read.

Comment: I attempted to edit the formatting of this post to make it correctly readable. Please make sure I didn't break it.

Comment: Can you show us some example input and what the erroneous output is? And what the output you expect is?

Comment: You don't state what the problem is. What is breaking? Reduce your code down to a simple demonstration of the lines that do not give your desired result.

Comment: Actually you have to deal with escaped backslashes only in literal strings. In all other cases just use `quoted form of` and AppleScript will do the rest.

Comment: Sorry for the formatting I'm pretty new to stackoverflow. If I want to make this: "find . -name '*.pmr' -exec rm {} \;" into a string in applescript it freaks out because "\" is an escape character. i've tried using "\\" but when i do applescript returns "\\" not "\"

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to escape a backslash with a backslash to pass on that string.

```
set foo to "\\"
```

will set foo to a single "\". You can verify this using any of the following:

```
display dialog foo
log foo
return foo
do shell script "echo \\$foo"
```

Run this last command, and it returns "$foo", proving that the shell command correctly received a single slash, which in this instance tells the shell command to ignore the special significance of $. If it had sent two slashes to the shell command, you would've gotten an error, or possibly a literal slash.
You can psych yourself out by getting confused by your editor's display of "\", but the results end up working.
You don't state in your question what is making you think it's not behaving correctly. What does "it freaks out" mean?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure everything out using bash commands mostly. Then I was able to create a service which ran when i hit a certain key set like "cmd + option + R." All the user has to do is select the folder and hit the keys and the program will erase all of the files with the specific extension. step 2 from my notes below allow bash to recognize the source which is determined by the first open window of Finder.

Again sorry for all the formatting trouble this is only my second ever post in stackoverflow

first modify the .bash_profile. Open it via terminal

1. open ~/.bash_profile -a TextEdit

copy and past script into the txt file then save. This allows you to now issue a command “cdf”

2. cdf () {
   theFinderPath=`osascript <<END
   tell application "Finder"
   try
       set thePath to get the POSIX path of (folder of the front window as string)
   on error
       set thePath to get the POSIX path of (path to desktop folder as string)
   end try
   end tell
   END`

   cd "$theFinderPath";
   }

rewrite script to include new command and then save this to the root of your “Documents” folder.

3.

## ! /bin/bash

## cd to the path of the front Finder window

cdf
find . -name ‘*.doc’ -exec rm {} \;       #deletes all doc files
find . -name ‘*.exe’ -exec rm {} \;       #deletes all exe files

Now using Automator you can write a simple code that will issue this command from a keystroke.

4. bash -x /Users/username/Documents/sh/script.sh || true